# Cloud file sharing service with LAN synchronisation? (besides Dropbox)

Tags: webapp-rec

What other file sharing services are out there, that also sync over the LAN (to circumvent narrow upstream bandwidth)?

Comment: Despite my comments below, DropBox is brilliant I just upgraded and continue to use it everyday. It is really good and helpful. Only $10 worth it - plus you can backup ANY file format.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a web based filesharing solution, but then you can always sync folders over the LAN within the same workgroup (assuming you're on windows).
Try using a folder sync tool like Belvedere.

Answer (score 0):

[LiveDrive](http://www.livedrive.com/) - very good! Free and universal on Mac and Windows.

Comment: Good to note though, this costs money!

Comment: Yes this does cost money now. LiveDrive, DropBox - cloud services that are free and cost for larger space. I would just use your own server. Get a Rackspace Cloud Server for example and use nginx/cdn setup and does this yourself or Amazon S3 and share the bucket folder on your PC/Mac with cloudBerry. Depending on the phone you can also remote connect to that folder and sync after 1 min - so always in sync.